# Add global jquery variable in class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS class:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import dt from 'datatables.net';

class ProductBuilder {

    constructor() {
        this.events()
    } // end constructor

    events() {
        $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this))
        $(".btn.btn-danger.btn-sm").on("click", this.ourClickDispatcher.bind(this))
    }

     ourClickDispatcher(e) {
    //initializing pressedButton the first time
     var pressedButton = $(e.target).closest(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm");

        if (pressedButton.data('exists') == 'Product') {
            console.log("cpu clicked")
            this.loadData('cpu')
        }
    }

    loadData(part) {
        //this function loads the data
    }

    addToTable(e) {
        //here the same button is initializing as in ourClickDispatcher
        var pressedButton = $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm");
    }
}

export default ProductBuilder;
```

I would like to add a global variable to caputer the `pressedButton` and not always searching for it via jquery, like the following:

```
var pressedButton = $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm");
```

I tried to add the `pressedButton` to the constructor as below, however this gives me the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pressedButton is not defined`

```
constructor() {
    pressedButton
    this.events()
} // end constructor
```

Any suggestions how to define the `pressedButton` as global variable?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly want a Global (which is rarely a good idea), you have to declare it in the Global Scope (outside of all functions and blocks. Then, you can set it from anywhere.

Here's an example that is easily applied to any code.

```js
var clickedButton = null; // Globally declared variable

$("button").on("click", function(){
  clickedButton = this;
  console.log(clickedButton.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.pressedButton = $(".btn.btn-primary.btn-sm");
    this.events()
}
```

Use it as `this.pressedButton` inside the class wherever required.

Docs: [Classes - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)